# Where do I initialize Firebase JS SDK inside Ionic4 + Angular project?

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have a simple question: Where do I initialize the firebase SDK's inside Ionic4 + Angular project?

is it inside the `app.module.ts` file? Or in the `app.component.ts` file? I tried to initialize it inside the `app.module.ts` but without success (using code below):

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';
import { IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app'; //I get an error here

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    firebase.initializeApp(environment.firebase)
  ],
  providers: [{ provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

But I get an error saying (line with the `firebase.initializeApp(environment.firebase`)):

```
Type 'App' is not assignable to type 'any[] | Type<any> | ModuleWithProviders<{}>'.
Type 'App' is missing the following properties from type 'Type<any>': apply, call, bind, prototype, and 4 more.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use Firebase with an Angular project you'll have to use [angular/fire](https://github.com/angular/angularfire) which is the officially supported package for Angular and Firebase development.

The most basic configuration can be found in their quickstart guide [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/install-and-setup.md) and will look something like this in your app module

```ts
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire/compat';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase)
  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```